# A simple question about ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So the problem begins with this condition: Let $R$ be a ring with for every $x \in R, x^2 = x$. I need to show the following properties hold.

1. For every $x \in R, x = -x$.
2. $R$ is commutative.
3. $xy + yx = 0$, for every $x,y \in R$.

I am having a hard time with this problem, could anyone kindly explain why these hold?

Comment: Why don't you try expanding some binomials.. knowing that R^2 + R for any R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1) note that $x = -x$ if and only if $x + x = 0$. We can show that $x+x=0$ by showing that $x+x = n(x+x)$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$. In this proof we will do it for $n = 2$ because it's convenient:

$$ (x+x)=(x+x)^2 = x^2 + 2x^2 + x^2 = x + x + x + x = (x+x) + (x+x)$$

hence $x+x = 0$.

For (2) you have to show that $xy = yx$ for all $x,y \in R$.

For (3) you can use (1) and (2).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was pretty helpful, yet I still have a question yet clarified. How do we know that xy = yx for all x,y?

Comment: @JohnLee $$x+y=(x+y)^2\\x+y=x^2+y^2+xy+yx\\x+y=x+y+xy+yx\\xy+yx=0$$

Comment: Oh, it was quite straight forward. Thanks a lot, so much helpful!